# How to Inject Data from ionic app to ionic webview controller

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

Hello i have one question, is it possible to send any data from ionic app to ionic webview controller? I want to make one ionic application with webview, and with webview i want to open my html website, and is it possible to send data this html site input compononet from the ionic application. Thank you.

Comment: I feel a bit confused since Ionic apps run in a webview. Do you mean In App Browser?

Comment: yes of course with In App Browser @C.Champagne

Comment: which is this for [ionic3] or [ionic4]?

Comment: it doesn't matter to me, for me is important with ionic to make this  @rtpHarry